# How to convert openerp 7 calendar

Tags: javascript, python, calendar, odoo

It's a short time that I am using openerp. I want to develop it, so that it uses Solar Hijri (Jalali) calendar (I don't need to change the dates in the database, I just want the users to interact with this type of dates --maybe a java script wrapper conversion).

I know java script and python to convert two dates `Gregorian <-> Jalali` , but I don't know how to port it to openerp. Can anybody help me do the task?

Answer (score 2):

using this javascript lib http://farhadi.ir/projects/jalalijscalendar/ you can create web module.

Comment: please add link only (one liner) answers as Comments!

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by making a separate widget for "Jalali" calendar. How to make a widget, you can follow this documentation : https://openerp-web-v7.readthedocs.org/en/latest/ or https://doc.openerp.com/trunk/web/